# Is ReplyingKafkaTemplate blocking?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Is [ReplyingKafkaTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#replying-template) blocking? Any reactive alternative?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't block under normal circumstances, it returns a `ListenableFuture` which can be used to either block (`get()`) or get the reply asynchronously with a listenable.

It will, however, block waiting for topic metadata when the first message is sent so it's not reactive.

There is the [reactor-kafka project](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka), but Spring Kafka does not currently use it.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/559) that we plan to look at for the next (2.3) release.

Comment: As part of this pull request, is there a also a plan to implement a fully reactive interface specifically for the functionality provided by ReplyingKafkaTemplate? This would be super helpful for reactive web services that interact with Kafka in a request/response manner.